# To sign raw transaction with Segwit Address in the TestNet

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, segregated-witness, p2wpkh, signrawtransaction

I am using Bitcoin core 0.14.1 testnet. I created a Segwit address. transfer some coins to this address. Now I want to spend it. I created a raw transaction using console command i.e. ***createrawtransaction***. Now I want to sign it. I tried using usual way i.e

***signrawtransaction*** 'hex_got_from_rawtx' '[{"txid":"","vout": index,"scriptPubkey":"","redeemScript":""}]' '["Private_key_of_address_used_in_segwit_address"]'

I am getting the error is: "*witness program hash mismatch*"

Any idea how can I get rid of it?

Comment: How did you create the segwit address? Did you use `addwitnessaddress`?

Comment: Yes, exactly.I used the same.

Comment: But I got to know that, I can't be able to retrieve back the address. I.e. I used addwitnessaddress "Address" then I got one address which is result of above query. Now I forgot the original  address and not able to retrieve it. Without this I can't sign rawtx i.e. dumpprivkey is only valisd on address not witness address.

Comment: Was the address you used in `addwitnessaddress` an address from the Bitcoin Core wallet or from elsewhere?

Comment: Yes The address was from bitcoin core wallet of mine only. If I use validateaddress "Multisig_address" then I am getting back all the addresses which I have used to create Multisig_address but if I use validateaddress "Segwit_address" then I am not getting the address which i have used to create Segwit_address.